# get a 2d matrix out of a 3d matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3d `m`x`n`x`t` matrix , I want to be able to extract `t` 2d `n`x`m` matrices.
In my case I have a 1024x1024x10 matrix and I want to have 10 images showing it to me.

This is not reshaping, I want just part of the data each time, is there a way doing it simpler that just coping member by member the data needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just do e.g.:

```
my_2d_array = my_3d_array(:,:,n);
```

For more info, see e.g. http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-86528.html.

Answer (score 5):

as Oliver said you can use:

```
my_2d_array = my_3d_array(:,:,n);
```

You can use squeeze function to remove the 1*1 of the matrix.

Comment: what happens when another dimension is, by chance, also singleton? Will that get removed too?

Comment: Yes. Try to run this: size(squeeze(zeros(10, 1, 10, 1, 2))). The output would look like: ans = 10    10     2